# PHP Nested Array - extract specific items from array

Tags: php, arrays, nested

i have the following array of data following a json_decode that i would like to extract all instances of [id] (except the ones under [contact]) to another array. I have tried array_column, but not getting the expected results. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstName] => John
                    [lastName] => Doe
                    [photoURL] => 
                    [Contact] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 43534554542
                            [type] => contacts
                        )

                    [webUrl] => https://www.google.com
                    [id] => extract_this_id
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [firstName] => John
                    [lastName] => Doe
                    [photoURL] => 
                    [Contact] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 43534554543
                            [type] => contacts
                        )

                    [webUrl] => https://www.google.com
                    [id] => extract_this_id
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_column` should work. Just make sure you look in the "data" key. So assuming your input is stored in `$response`, it would be:

```
$result = array_column($response["data"], "id");
```

See it run in [this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6f640342d4df071934851de75393deefca56751)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you are trying to get the list of id in a new array, then you can try use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

example:

```php
$data = [
           [
              'firstName' => 'John',
              'lastName' => 'Doe',
              'photoURL' => 'some url',
              'contact' => [
                 'id' => 312212,
                 'type' => 'contacts'
              ],
              'webUrl' => 'some url',
              'id' => 3,
          ],
          [
              'firstName' => 'Jane',
              'lastName' => 'Doe',
              'photoURL' => 'some url',
              'contact' => [
                  'id' => 121311,
                  'type' => 'contacts'
              ],
              'webUrl' => 'some url',
              'id' => 4,
          ],
    ];

    $ids = array_map(function ($itemRow) {
        return $itemRow['id'];
    }, $data);

   // output [3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks, both answers are useful, but the solution by @trincot was what i was looking for. Stupid me was omitting the "data" key